Git index keeps breaking
I currently have a very strange behavior in my WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). Whenever I change a file within a working copy of a repository git status does not report any changes. I have to delete the index and reset it. Then the changes are detected. If I change the same file or another again. I have to go through the same process. What is wrong here?
What I tested:

Different repositories: Existing ones with remote and also freshly created ones (git init) without remote.

Different editors: neovim, nano

Different strategies for 'fixing' the issue:
Option 1:
git rm --cached README.md
git reset 

Option 2:
rm .git/index
git reset



I use the file README.md as a placeholder. But it happens to all files in all repositories tested.
The file change is not detected by either of the following:

git status
git diff
git commit -a
git checkout .

What I also find interesting: in the detailed view of eza with the git column, the file is reported as modified.
I tested my git setup in a newly created Ubuntu 24.04 WSL where it is working.
What have I messed up?
Troubleshooting

There is no parallel access from Windows; The repo is in within the home directory of the WSL.

There is no IDE running (e.g. code .) which accesses the repo and tries to update the status. At least I am not aware of anything. I also tried after a fresh restart of the Laptop and the WSL.

Especially in the newly created test repository there is no .gitignore file present. The other repositories were working previously.
As multiple repositories are affected, I checked for a global gitignore configuration and could not find anything. I also checked with git check-ignore README.md and git check-ignore --no-index README.md.

which git --> /usr/bin/git

echo $PATH lists the Linux paths before the Windows paths. Thus, we should be using the linux version of git

git --version --> 2.25.1 I do not get a newer version via apt. Maybe I need to switch to the ppa.



Are you using WSL1 or WSL2? I assume the repo is in a Windows folder? Are you by any chance also accessing the repo from windows at the same time? Maybe by having an IDE open that automatically refreshes some status?

good questions: It is WSL 2, It is in a WSL-only directory and not accessed by windows. There is no IDE running (I am aware of), which refreshes the status.

Is the file being ignored by .gitignore configuration?

I do not think so. Especially in the newly created repo there is no .gitignore file at all. I just checked if there would be a global gitignore and could not find something. I tested with git check-ignore and also git check-ignore --no-index

which git? echo $PATH? Maybe Windows Git is found before Linux Git?

Is your repository on a shared network drive of some sort?

@matt no, the repository is not on a network drive

@JeffRSon: That is a very interesting idea. I double checked and I should be using the Linux version. Which is backed by showing a way older version than under Windows.

Updating my git version to 2.46.2 by the instructions solved the issue.
As other WSL instances are working fine with 2.25.1 (and the one in question was until recently), I suspect that something was broken with my git installation. Maybe an uninstall and reinstall would also have solved it. But now I have a recent version anyway.
